# Django - how to fix an empty search bar that is returning all items

Tags: django, django-views

I have a search bar. When i try to search without putting any word, it returns all the items from my models.

here's is my views.py for search bar

```
def Search(request):
queryset = Book.objects.all()
query = request.GET.get('q')
if query:
    queryset = queryset.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query)  |
        Q(genre__name__icontains=query) 
    ).distinct()
context = {
    'queryset': queryset
}
return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
```

i just want to render in my template that there's no match in his query, instead of returning the list of all items.

Comment: You can do it by using an `else` condition in which if `query` is `None`, return `None` in `queryset` in `context` and in `html file`, check `if queryset is None` display `There's no match`

Comment: i just tried it by now but it's now working.. Maybe my syntax is wrong or something, i don't know.

Comment: @GiranyxPornasdoro what did you write in your else statement? You can try queryset = queryset.filter(pk__in=[-1])

Comment: where do i put that filter? before Q(incontains) or should i re-write it all over?